# Form processing won't pass value

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code which permits me to do a request in order to make a query!

Now the form which is processed has this code:

```
<form action="edit_images.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<? echo $gal_id1 ?>" name="img_id1"  />
<input type="submit" value="Edit All Images"  />
</form>
```

While the query is like this :

```
$img_id=$_REQUEST['img_id1'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE Img_gal_id='$img_id'";
```

But it seems like it won't take the value...
I mean, it doesn't recognize the $img_id, which i have printed before and takes the exact value.

Let me show you the query i use in order to retrieve it:

```
$sql = "SELECT gal_id,gal_title,gal_image FROM tbl_galleries where gal_id='" . $_REQUEST['gid'] ."';";
      $query = mysql_query($sql) or $myErrorsP = mysql_error();
      if(isset($myErrors) && $myErrorsP!=''){     
      } else {          
          $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
          mysql_free_result($query);
          $gal_id    = $row[0];
          $gal_id1    = $row[0];
          $gal_title = $row[1];
          $gal_image = $row[2];                     
      }
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: what is the type of the Img_gal_id, if INT do not qoute the $img_id...$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE Img_gal_id=$img_id";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `;` on the end of your `echo` that isn't outputting the value as expected. Additionally, you are using short tags, which could be causing problems. You might want to swtich to using `<?php` as an opening over `<?` on it's own.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $gal_id1; ?>" name="img_id1"  />
```

Lastly, you are using *zero* protection against injection attacks. Please, research prepared statements in PDO and update your code. The first injection attack you *don't* have will thank you for it.

Edit: When you run into a problem like this, it is often good practice to echo out the `$sql` just before you execute it.

you could do this in the future with:

```
$sql = "SELECT gal_id,gal_title,gal_image FROM tbl_galleries where gal_id='" . $_REQUEST['gid'] ."';";
echo $sql."<br>\n";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or $myErrorsP = mysql_error();
```

which would have probably given you an excellent indication of what the problem was.